# Drawing tile field in AIR/Flex4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, mxml, flex4.6

I have this field of rectangles:

[image]

Any ideas how can draw it using available components like label or maybe rectangle?

I planned to use BorderContainer and to add labels with colored border but I am not sure if it is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely one of the cheapest ones. Under label you only have TextBase, but unless you're really pointing out for max performance, start with your original idea: Label with spark BorderContainer.

If you want to go a step further you would be using flash and draw the movie clip yourself. But at that point if you ask me, you're loosing the benefit of using Flex in the first place.

Hope this helps, go with your idea.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of items that will be shown on the screen.

I'd choose a custom UI component which can draw a square path for your and print TextField.

If the future of the application requires you to skin the buttons, then this is not the way you should be proceeding. Use labels if it needs heavy skinning, so you can take advantage of skin classes.

more on [path](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS5B6A8436-0FF5-4029-8524-C7C1106C483D.html) and [TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532902/how-do-i-draw-text-in-an-actionscript-3-sprite)